How to change the position of jrxml elements from java class?
File jrxmlFile = new File("E:\\JAVAFX Project\\Report\\src\\Reports\\firstReport.jrxml");
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxmlFile);

JRDesignStaticText staticText = (JRDesignStaticText) jasperDesign.getDetailSection().getBands()[0].getElementByKey("IdStaticText");

staticText.setX(150);
staticText.setY(54); 
            
JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(filepath);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, dataSource);

Above code does not position the static text according to the coordinates mentioned.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you make changes to the in memory JasperDesign object make sure you compile that object instead of the JRXML file on disk:
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

